# How to execute function parallel : Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I am trying to execute below code in parallel using multiprocessing but I am not getting proper output.

Iteration with 1 and iteration  with 5 should happen in parallel

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
def func1(x):
    i = x
    while i < 10:
        print(str(i)+" fun1")
        i +=1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=1) 
    pool.map(func1, [1,5])
```

Result I got: happening more iterations

> 1 fun1 2 fun1 3 fun1 4 fun1 5 fun1 6 fun1 7 fun1 8 fun1 9 fun1 5 fun1
>   6 fun1 7 fun1 8 fun1 9 fun1

Expected output: both iterations should happen in parallel

> 1 fun1 5 fun1 2 fun1 6 fun1 3 fun1 7 fun1 4 fun1 8 fun1 5 fun1 9 fun1
>   6 fun1 7 fun1 8 fun1 9 fun1

Comment: i updated the question please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your result with your code. I'm getting the expected behavior (note the call of 'func1' before the 'if' statement):

> 1 fun1 2 fun1 3 fun1 4 fun1 5 fun1 6 fun1 7 fun1 8 fun1 9 fun1 1 fun1
>   2 fun1 3 fun1 4 fun1 5 fun1 6 fun1 7 fun1 8 fun1 9 fun1 5 fun1 6 fun1
>   7 fun1 8 fun1 9 fun1

For some reason, you're calling func1(1) three times.

In any case, you start 1 process only, so the execution will be serial. You need more than one process to get parallel execution.

Comment: i have updated the code can you please have a look...i  used 2 process but still same result

Comment: are you expecting an alternate printing? If so, it is very unlikely if you do not force the processes to wait the others.

Answer (score 1):

What you are expecting is not happening due to the Global Interpreter Lock. Give it a look: https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock

Comment: multiprocessing works around that by using multiple processes, each of which has its own lock. I'd say the `processes=1` is what restricts this code, as well as the simple fact the job is so short one may finish before the other is told what to do. Thirdly, the job isn't productive; `map` would normally collect the return values.